# How to sumifs based on date and time in excel?

Tags: excel, formula, sumifs

**How to sum based on date and time?**

Dear Respected Team, there are many examples of sumifs based on Date_range on internet but I could not get any formula that how to sumifs based on date_and_time range.

I mean how to **Sum** Per_Day_Charges from 24-10-2020 20:04:00 to 26-10-2020 01:35:00?

**Data are mentioned below.**

Date & Time Per Day charges

21-09-2020 18:16:00 100

22-10-2020 12:22:00 100

23-10-2020 11:30:00 100

24-10-2020 19:52:00 100

24-10-2020 20:04:00 100

24-10-2020 23:10:00 100

25-10-2020 06:10:00 100

25-10-2020 16:35:00 100

25-10-2020 17:25:00 100

26-10-2020 01:06:00 100

26-10-2020 01:35:00 100

26-10-2020 03:12:00 100

26-10-2020 03:42:00 100

26-10-2020 03:44:00 100

26-10-2020 03:49:00 100

[image: SUM ONLY PINK BACKGROUND CELLS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't overthink this.

Put the two boundary date/times into two cells and reference these two cells in a Sumifs.

```
=SUMIFS(B3:B17,A3:A17,">="&F3,A3:A17,"<="&F4)
```

[image]

If you don't want to use cells for the comparison, keep in mind that a date/time value is just a date and a time added together, so you can also use

```
=SUMIFS(B3:B17,A3:A17,">="&(DATE(2020,10,24)+TIME(20,4,0)),A3:A17,"<="&(DATE(2020,10,26)+TIME(1,35,0)))
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much **Ms. Teylyn**. I think this is the first **Sumifs** formula based on date and time criteria.